# Access Json Structure in VB.Net

Tags: json, vb.net, linq, json.net

I have just started the parse the Json structure in my program. 
My ServerResponse is look like as follows.

I dont know how to paste the json structure here. Therefore i just copy and paste the structure here.

```
{
"pot_searches": [
    {
        "id": 24,
        "links": {
            "results": [
                {
                    "type": "pot_search_results",
                    "id": 191
                },
                {
                    "type": "pot_search_results",
                    "id": 192
                },
                {
                    "type": "pot_search_results",
                    "id": 193
                },
                {
                    "type": "pot_search_results",
                    "id": 194
                },
                {
                    "type": "pot_search_results",
                    "id": 195
                },
                {
                    "type": "pot_search_results",
                    "id": 196
                },
                {
                    "type": "pot_search_results",
                    "id": 197
                },
                {
                    "type": "pot_search_results",
                    "id": 198
                },
                {
                    "type": "pot_search_results",
                    "id": 199
                },
                {
                    "type": "pot_search_results",
                    "id": 200
                }
            ],
            "query_tree": null
        },
        "description": "hello example",
        "query_text": "Heat",
        "limit": 10,
        "error": null,
        "created_by": null,
        "href": "http://blabla/bla/bla/pot/searches/24"
    },
    {
        "id": 25,
        "links": {
            "results": [
                {
                    "type": "pot_search_results",
                    "id": 201
                },
                {
                    "type": "pot_search_results",
                    "id": 202
                },
                {
                    "type": "pot_search_results",
                    "id": 203
                },
                {
                    "type": "pot_search_results",
                    "id": 204
                },
                {
                    "type": "pot_search_results",
                    "id": 205
                },
                {
                    "type": "pot_search_results",
                    "id": 206
                },
                {
                    "type": "pot_search_results",
                    "id": 207
                },
                {
                    "type": "pot_search_results",
                    "id": 208
                },
                {
                    "type": "pot_search_results",
                    "id": 209
                },
                {
                    "type": "pot_search_results",
                    "id": 210
                }
            ],
            "query_tree": null
        },
        "description": "hello example",
        "query_text": "Heat",
        "limit": 10,
        "error": null,
        "created_by": null,
        "href": "http://blabla/bla/bla/pot/searches/25"
    }
],
"linked": {
    "pot_search_results": [
        {
            "links": {
                "Pemash": {
                    "type": "pot_browse_contents",
                    "href": "http://blabla/bla/bla/pot/pots/5a267e98-0a12-4110-bac3-575439cb6097",
                    "id": "5a267e98-0a12-4110-bac3-575439cb6097"
                },
                "found_terms": [
                    {
                        "type": "pot_search_found_terms",
                        "id": 780
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "pot_search_found_terms",
                        "id": 781
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "pot_search_found_terms",
                        "id": 782
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "pot_search_found_terms",
                        "id": 783
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "pot_search_found_terms",
                        "id": 784
                    }
                ]
            },
            "id": 191,
            "score": 13.765055790063306
        },
        {
            "links": {
                "Pemash": {
                    "type": "pot_browse_contents",
                    "href": "http://blabla/bla/bla/pot/pots/5a267e98-0a12-4110-bac3-575439cb6097",
                    "id": "5a267e98-0a12-4110-bac3-575439cb6097"
                },
                "found_terms": [
                    {
                        "type": "pot_search_found_terms",
                        "id": 785
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "pot_search_found_terms",
                        "id": 786
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "pot_search_found_terms",
                        "id": 787
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "pot_search_found_terms",
                        "id": 788
                    }
                ]
            },
            "id": 192,
            "score": 10.669084946432259
        },
        {
            "links": {
                "Pemash": {
                    "type": "pot_browse_contents",
                    "href": "http://blabla/bla/bla/pot/pots/5a267e98-0a12-4110-bac3-575439cb6097",
                    "id": "5a267e98-0a12-4110-bac3-575439cb6097"
                },
                "found_terms": [
                    {
                        "type": "pot_search_found_terms",
                        "id": 789
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "pot_search_found_terms",
                        "id": 790
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "pot_search_found_terms",
                        "id": 791
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "pot_search_found_terms",
                        "id": 792
                    }
                ]
            },
            "id": 193,
            "score": 10.669084946432259
        },
```

**NOW here is my VB.NET code:**

```
Dim json As String = responseFromServer
Dim ser As JObject = JObject.Parse(json)

Dim data As List(Of JToken) = ser.Children().tolist() 'VisualStudio shows me error here that ToList is not a member of Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken

Dim output As String = ""
```

So that i cannot save the children in the lists. Can you please tell me that how can I access the href elements in the json structure under "Linked" child with vb.net.

I shall be very thankful to you if you provide me one example to access the following line from Json Structure with vb.net code.

href": "http://blabla/bla/bla/pot/pots/5a267e98-0a12-4110-bac3-575439cb6097"

Comment: What error does it show on that line? In all likelihood, you may not need the `()` if `Children` is a property, not a method. I haven't used JObject in quite some time (I find Json.Net far more useful/flexible).

Comment: i have also tried this but no suceess.......Dim data As List(Of JToken) = ser.Children().ToList.... Visual Studio Shows me error that "ToList is not a member of Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken"

Comment: Do you have the `System.Linq` namespace imported?

Comment: I have added follwoing: <<BR>> Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.  Do you have `Imports System.Linq`?

Comment: By the way, you there is no way to make multi-line comments, so don't even try :)  Because of that, it's generally not a good idea to put anything longer than a short snippet of code in a comment.  If you surround the code with single-quotes, it will format it as a source-code (fixed width font with a gray background)

Comment: no i dont have this one. when i add this one then i get error that: Namespace or tpye specified in the Imports 'System.Linq' desnot contain any public member or annot be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ToList` method is an [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx) to the `IEnumerable(Of T)` interface.  It is defined in the `System.Linq` namespace by the **System.Core.dll** library.  Therefore, unless you reference that library and import that namespace, you will not see the `ToList` method on any enumerable object.  `ToList` is not a method that is defined by the enumerable types, themselves.  It is a method that is automatically appended to the type's interface by that library, but only when the library that extends it is referenced and the namespace imported.

[LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx), along with all of its extension methods, were added in the 3.5 version of the .NET Framework, so you won't have access to any of it if your project is targeting 3.0 or earlier.

Comment: Thank you very  much Steven Doggart for quick help. I am very thankful to you. Now i can Access ToList for children. Now i develop program for accessing the href vaule in json. Thanks again dear...see u on next time :)

Comment: now i cannot Access the "Pemash" items. :(. i try to post my code here. Maybe then you can help me.

Comment: I suggest posting it as a new question rather than adding here.  I may not be able to help you because I don't know anything about that JSON library in particular.  If you ask it as a new question, people will be more likely to see it and help you.